# How can I retrieve this in laravel?

Tags: laravel

Flowing query  is working fine on mysql database but how can I retrieve this in laravel? code of mysql is given bellow:

```
select count('brand_id') from products where brand_id=3
```

Comment: you want a language specific query conversion, what have you researched or tried  in Laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
$number = 3;
DB::table('products')->where('brand_id',$number)->count();
```

But I recommend using Models

```
Product::where('brand_id',$number)->count();
```

Answer (score 1):

Following what laravel has on https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries at the aggregates topic:

`$products = DB::table('products')->where('brand_id', 3)->count();`

Comment: the count must be after the where clause.

Comment: My bad, i just fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

As @PlayMa256 said, you can do exactly this query using

```
DB::table('products')->where('brand_id', 3)->count();
```

BUT, if you have defined your models correctly, you can do this directly using you model class. If your model is called `Product`, then:

```
Product::where('brand_id', 3)->count();
```

Another awesome way to do this is by using the magic methods for where clause:

```
Product::whereBrandId(3)->count();
```